# New asphalt is coarse instead of smooth

Tags: driveway, asphalt

A local paving company paved my driveway a week ago and I noticed the appearance is not smooth in some spots. Is this level of coarseness normal? Wondering if this is a concern for the longevity of the pavement.

[image: New ashphalt]
[image: New asphalt close up]

Comment: Sealing it would help protect it an make it look more uniform in color/texture. It's not ideal to have to re-seal a new surface, but it's cheap-ish and easy compared to alternative fixes.

Comment: Kinda looks like the asphalt plant went light on the binder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with you. That is definitely not a good job.

Contact them and see if they will come to fix it.

If not you will have to do it yourselves which is not a simple job since special tools are needed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Some of those spots look like they need more asphalt mixed in with the aggregate. Some of those stones will kick up pretty easy. I'd get the paving company out there and see what they say.

How did they compact it?

Comment: To be honest I don't know how they compacted it. Maybe they didn't use the right machine?